# How to clone details of one user to another | Oracle |

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have been trying to implement a code which should clone details of one user to another.

**Table :** `Employee`

**Below is the data in employee table :**

```
Name | Age | Access | URL 
Raj  | 22  | Y      | google
Raj  | 22  | Y      | Youtube 
Raj  | 22  | N      | Udemy 
Bob  | 24  | Y      | Spotify
```

**Expected output :**   Cloned the user `Raj` to `Bob` all his access

```
Name | Age | Access | URL 
Raj  | 22  | Y      | google
Raj  | 22  | Y      | Youtube 
Raj  | 22  | N      | Udemy 
Bob  | 24  | Y      | Spotify 
Bob  | 24  | Y      | google
Bob  | 24  | Y      | Youtube 
Bob  | 24  | N      | Udemy
```

I can achieve it by using `cursor` , but the problem with the `cursor` is not good when their is large amount of data in table.

Any other approach through which I can get it done will be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Insert` + `not exists` might be one option:

```
insert into employee (name, age, access, url)
select 'Bob', b.age, b.access, b.url            --> new user
from employee b
where b.name = 'Raj'                            --> existing user
and not exists (select null
                from employee c
                where c.name = 'Bob'            --> new user
                  and c.age = b.age
                  and c.access = b.access
                  and c.url = b.url);
```

Parametrize it, if you want (i.e. pass old/new names as parameters).

---

BTW, `access` is a reserved word and can't be used as a column name:

```
SQL> create table test (access number);
create table test (access number)
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier


SQL>
```

Comment: Can it be possible to avoid making duplicate entries for same user Bob. For example : Bob as access to Google and Raj as access to Google this should not be inserted. How to achieve in above code

Comment: NOT EXISTS should take care about that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO Employee dst
USING (
  SELECT 'Bob' AS name, 24 AS age, "ACCESS", url
  FROM   employee
  WHERE  name = 'Raj'
) src
ON (src.name = dst.name AND src.url = dst.url)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET "ACCESS" = src."ACCESS"
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (name, age, "ACCESS", url)
  VALUES (src.name, src.age, src."ACCESS", src.url);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=656604ef5f148b72f931256bc54c3b00)*